# How to iterate through a list of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, stl, iterator

I'm very new to C++ and struggling to figure out how I should iterate through a list of objects and access their members.

I've been trying this where `data` is a `std::list` and `Student` a class.

```
std::list<Student>::iterator<Student> it;
for (it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout<<(*it)->name;
}
```

and getting the following error:

```
error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Student’
```

Comment: First you need to read more about how to declare iterator variables. Hint: They are not templates. Secondly, while the iterator can in some ways be treated as a pointer, once you dereference it it's not longer a "pointer" but a value.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You're close.

```
std::list<Student>::iterator it;
for (it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << it->name;
}
```

Note that you can define `it` inside the `for` loop:

```
for (std::list<Student>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << it->name;
}
```

And if you are using C++11 then you can use a range-based `for` loop instead:

```
for (auto const& i : data) {
    std::cout << i.name;
}
```

Here `auto` automatically deduces the correct type. You could have written `Student const& i` instead.

Comment: For the C++11 version, what s the maximum number of elements before a possible internal loop indice is overflown if any? I m talking about Visual Studio and gcc on Linux.

Comment: @user2284570 There isn't any loop-index involved, only iterators.

Comment: @Deduplicator I was meaning internally by the compiler.

Comment: Excuse me, both `std::cout<<(*it).name;` and `std::cout<<it->name;` will work, right? Iterator can be regarded as pointer to the element.

Answer (score 21):

Since C++ 11, you could do the following:

```
for(const auto& student : data)
{
  std::cout << student.name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is `const` mandatory in range-based loop or is avoiding it a bad habbit?

Comment: It's a best-practice to prevent you (or whoever modifies it after you) from changing the contents of the vector as it's iterating. If you're implementing a transformative function, you may want to mutate the vector and therefore drop the const. But it's typically not recommended to write code that does that in most industry standards.

Comment: For the C++11 version, what s the maximum number of elements before a possible internal loop indice is overflown if any? I m talking about Visual Studio and gcc on Linux.

Comment: @user2284570 To my knowledge, you'll be limited to the maximum value of `std::vector<T>::size_type`, which is 2^64 / `sizeof(T)` (that is, the maximum number of objects that can be represented in the address space of memory. This is also why you shouldn't use STL containers to replace database in some situations.

Answer (score 4):

It is also worth to mention, that if you DO NOT intent to modify the values of the list, it is possible (and better) to use the `const_iterator`, as follows:

```
for (std::list<Student>::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it){
    // do whatever you wish but don't modify the list elements
    std::cout << it->name;
}
```

Comment: Since C++11 we have `cbegin()` and `cend()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you add an `#include <algorithm>` then you can use the `for_each` function and a lambda function like so:

```
for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [](Student *it) 
{
    std::cout<<it->name;
});
```

You can read more about the algorithm library at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

and about lambda functions in cpp at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3):

-> it works like pointer u don't have to use *

```
for( list<student>::iterator iter= data.begin(); iter != data.end(); iter++ )
cout<<iter->name; //'iter' not 'it'
```