# How to print out a found element from a STL List inside of a map?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void Cinema::movieRunningAt(Movie& m, std::list<int>& movieList)
{

    map<const Movie*, std::list<int>>::iterator mov_it;
    mov_it = movie_times.find(&m);

    if (mov_it == movie_times.end())
    {
        cout << "No movie was found" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << mov_it->second << endl;
}
```

second is a list, so how do I print the found element out?

```
cout << mov_it->second << endl;
```

?

Comment: that map is *very very* strange, it maps Movie pointer to lists if ints.

Comment: having said that ->second is a list<int> you cannot just cout a list. You have to choose some elements from the list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269435/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-objects-in-c

Answer (score 0):

> mov_it->second is a list container print it element need again traverse
>    Examples are as follows

```
map<int, list<int>> mapContainer{ {1, {1,2,3}}, {2, {2, 3, 4}} };
map<int, list<int>>::iterator it = mapContainer.find(1);
if (it != mapContainer.end())
{
    for (int element : it->second)
    {
        cout << element << endl;
    }
}
```