# Is it ideal to put data inside a private class? (C++)

Tags: c++, class

For example, I have this class:

```
struct bankingFunctionality
{
private:
    class bankingData
    {
    public:
        int phoneNum, citizenNum, age, ID;
        string name, address;
        bankingData* next = nullptr;
    };

public:
    void input(bankingData*);
    void firstUser();
    void update(bankingData*);
};
```

Is it ideal to put the data class in private to "protect" data? Since the only way, I can think of how to access it for input and output is to have functions like void input(...) in public. However, every time I want to call input I would need to create a new object and waste memory.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do here? You're comparing your option against an alternative, but I'm not sure I see what that alternative is or what the concerns you have with it are. If you edit your question to show the other option and what you don't like about it, we can offer alternatives and general feedback on it.

Comment: PIMPL may be something you look into: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pimpl-idiom-in-c-with-examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pimpl-idiom-in-c-with-examples/) depending on what your motivations for this are.

Comment: If your public member functions allow a user of the class to access a nested type, that nested type needs to also be public.   For example, to use your member function `input()` or `update()` the caller (or a caller of the caller) would need to be able to create an instance of `bankingData`, in order to pass its address.    If `bankingData` is `private` then the caller cannot create an instance of `bankingData` unless the caller is a member of your class or a `friend`.

Comment: It’s not clear why you would need to create a new object for every call to input(); you could Instead keep a single object (eg as a member-variable or a local variable) and use that.

Comment: Note in C++ you'll want to use `const` references (`const bankingData&`) whenever possible instead of C-style pointers. These provide a lot of benefits, but importantly it's much harder to pass in an accidental `nullptr`.

Comment: Another thing to note is C++ has a variety of generic containers to use, so rolling your own linked list is almost never necessary. Consider using `std::list` or `std::vector` here to encapsulate these.

Comment: As your code is not usable, it make the question pointless. Try to use `input` function and tell us how you can do it if `bankingData` is private. If a type is private, then essentially it means that it is useful only internally to the class.

Comment: The main purpose of the program is to get user data and built a linked list. Since all the data needed to be access and change, is putting the class in private unnecessary? Generally, when should we use class private?
P/S: I have never used a generic container before, so I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this as a way to pass in arguments it's really wasteful and you should consider the traditional `getX()` and `setX()` approach for accessors and mutators. You can make these easy to use in a chain style if you return `*this` at the end of each.

As in:

```
class bankingData {
  int phoneNum, citizenNum, age, ID;
  string name, address;
  bankingData* next = nullptr;

  int getPhoneNum() const { return phoneNum; };
  bankingData& setPhoneNum(int n) { phoneNum = n; return *this; };

  const std::string& getName() const { return name; };
  bankingData& setName(const std::string& n) { name = n; return *this; };
};
```

Where you can then do:

```
bankingData bd;

bd.setPhoneNum(111).setName(...);
```

Comment: Hey, I looked into using std::list <bankingData> test to do my linked list. However, how do I traverse the list? The provided functions don't really work with user-defined data type.

Comment: You can iterate over it like you would any other container.

Comment: This is a fairly [common pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269435/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-objects-in-c).

Comment: I realized that .end() is totally different than .begin(). I can't access anything with .end(). What is the difference between the two of them, and what is .end() really?

Comment: `end()` represents the "N" position in a 0..N-1 list. It's not an actual element. Often it's used to represent "nothing matched" when using `std::find`, etc.